# Use numpy bincount with weights for 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following 1d numpy arrays

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> y = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
```

and bins

```
>>> bins = np.array([0,0,1,1,2,3])
```

Then I may use bincount for each array like:

```
>>> np.bincount(bins, weights=x)
array([ 3.,  7.,  5.,  6.])
>>> np.bincount(bins, weights=y)
array([ 30.,  70.,  50.,  60.])
```

Can I perform both summaries at once ? I tried

```
>>> np.bincount(np.array([[0,0,1,1,2,3], [0,0,1,1,2,3]]), weights=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [10,20,30,40,50,60]]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
>>>
```

and got an error

Comment: Just to make you know, code snippets on Stack Overflow are only useful for HTML/JS/CSS, use simple formattation for Python.

Comment: AFAIK, no. You need to call `bincount` twice because it only supports 1D arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not possible. And one hint is that there isn't any `axis` argument that you can pass to `bincounts`. Your best bet is do them one-at-a-time:

```
bc = np.array([np.bincount(bins, weights=x), np.bincount(bins, weights=y)])
```

Or using list-comprehension:

```
bc = np.array([np.bincount(bins, weights=w) for w in [x, y]])
```

Output:

```
>>> bc
array([[ 3.,  7.,  5.,  6.],
       [30., 70., 50., 60.]])
```

Comment: Hello. I hope you are well. I haven't seen you for a few days. You've been suspended again :( I just wanted to tell you that I was going to stop StackOverflow for a while. I am looking for a new job and I need time! It was a pleasure to confront you and see you very soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate bincount with [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
xy = np.stack([x,y])
n = np.unique(bins).size
out = np.zeros((2,n), dtype=xy.dtype)
np.add.at(out, (slice(None), bins), xy)
```

output in `out`:

```
array([[ 3,  7,  5,  6],
       [30, 70, 50, 60]])
```

Comment: Nice answer! I am wondering if it is as much fast as bincount when summarise 1d arrays. My intention is to aggregate (sum) numeric column values, having as bins an id column, but do it once for all numeric columns and not separately for each one.

Comment: I believe `add.at` is slower than `bincount` for large 1d arrays since it does the operation unbuffered, i.e. `temp = out[i] + xy` followed by `out[i] = temp` where `i = (slice(None), bins)`. The [c-code](https://github.com/numpy/datetime/blob/main/numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c#L102) for bincount is a straight-forward implementation - compute the length of output and run the [for loop](https://github.com/numpy/datetime/blob/main/numpy/lib/src/_compiled_base.c#L159-L161). You can modify the source inside `numpy/core/src/multiarray` to fit your needs.

Comment: I referenced an old version of bincount, but the implemenation is the same on the latest version of numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c#L112